# MySQL Select count rows with specific attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Sorry for the title, but my problem it's difficult to explain.

I have a table called "TEL_LIST" with this fields:

- ID
- TELEPHONE
- STATUS

I have many rows for a single telephone number. The status may be YES or NO.

I want to count the total number of rows with status "NO" (without counting the "YES" rows) only for telephone numbers which have at least one "YES" status.

To make you understand better, I want this:

**EDIT:**

```
TEL:011, STATUS:YES
TEL:011, STATUS:NO
TEL:011, STATUS:NO
TEL:012, STATUS:NO
TEL:012, STATUS:NO
TEL:012, STATUS:NO
RESULT: 2.

TEL:011, STATUS:YES
TEL:011, STATUS:NO
TEL:011, STATUS:NO
TEL:012, STATUS:YES
TEL:012, STATUS:NO
TEL:012, STATUS:NO
RESULT: 4.
```

Perhaps I have not explained well:
I want the total number (the sum) of all "No" records which have at least one "Yes" record.

To make you understand well, I work in a contact center. I want the total of all negative calls (status: no) that have become positive (status: yes).

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Conditional Aggregate` to count the values

```
select TEL,
       count(case when STATUS = 'Yes' Then 1 end) AS Conditional_Count
from yourtable
Group by TEL
```

Another way would be

```
SUM(case when STATUS = 'Yes' Then 1 ELSE 0 end)
```

**Update:** Based on the clarification in question

```
select count(case when STATUS = 'NO' Then 1 end) AS Conditional_Count
from yourtable
Having count(case when STATUS = 'YES' Then 1 end) > 0
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I have not explained well. I want to count "No" rows of a telphone that has at least one "Yes" status. I don't want to count the Yes rows. Thank you!

Comment: @L.Soprano - Updated check now

Answer (score 0):

I think this follows your logic:

```
select tel,
       (case when sum(status = 'Yes') = 0 then 0
             else sum(status = 'No')
        end)
from t
group by tel;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this can help me:

```
select count(case when STATUS != 'YES' Then 1 end) AS TOT
from T
having (select count(case when STATUS='YES' Then 1 end) AS T)>0 AND TOT>0
```

I tried this solution but I'm not sure that the result is correct...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a left join and a group by query:

```
select t1.tel, count(t2.tel) AS total_no
from
  TEL t1 left join TEL t2
  on t1.tel=t2.tel AND t1.status='Yes' AND t2.status='No'
group by
  t1.tel
```

with an index on tel and status, performances should be optimal. Numbers that don't have any status='Yes' won't be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

select  x.Tel, count(distinct  x.Number)
from (
       select  t.Tel, case when tmp.tel is not null then Id else null end as Number
        from    yourtable t
         left outer join (
                            select  tel
                            from    yourtable 
                            where   status = 'Yes'
                         ) tmp on tmp.Tel = t.Tel
            where   t.status = 'No'
        ) x
group by    x.tel